# how transform R list to polygons

Tags: r, list, geospatial, r-sf, wkt

[image]The data is a csv with colum like this :

- "list(c(-72.6689780388482, -72.6697951984133, ...... -37.8155440677891, -37.8164165487739, ......))"
  The original archive is a .RDS file

My goal is convert the row GEOMETRY to the next aternatives:

1. get the polygon like   POLYGON(LON1,LAT1 LON2,LAT2)
2. get the list with lat and long splited
3. finally tranform entire colum to sf object for obtainn the geometry column

```
parsed<- list( 
  c(-72.6689780388482, -72.6697951984133,-37.8155440677891, -37.8164165487739)
)
result_b <- list( 
  lat = c(-72.6689780388482, -72.6697951984133 ) ,
  lon = c( -37.8155440677891, -37.8164165487739)
)
```

Comment: Please don't create a variable which is named `list`. It will overwrite the function `list()` in the global environment.

Comment: It seems odd to me that your CSV file has an R expression in a field. Perhaps you should ask the originator of that data to provide an `.rda` file instead, as that would preclude the need to (and risks of) read/parse/eval-ing the file contents.

Comment: the original archive is a .RDS file with R 3.6.3 then export this to csv , my actual env  use it R 4.1.2 and is incompatible with this version :/

Comment: Ummm ... I did not realize that an RDS file saved from R-3.6.0 could not be read by R-4. Is this documented? I haven't found it on a cursory search. I know you asked how to convert the "CSV" format into a polygon, but perhaps you would be better served by fixing the import process so you don't have to parse/eval/convert.

Comment: Ok @r2evans thks for your answer, also i think so this format is weir or not a standar gis

Comment: well i found the problem , only i have a export a new versión of the .RDS file with the version=2 parameter  like saveRDS(df_rds, file="new.RDS", version=2)

Comment: Hi @Cristián Vargas Acevedo. Don't know if this is still useful but I just posted below an answer. Hope it will help you. Cheers.

Comment: wow is a complete answer !! thx a lot

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. Glad that I could help. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Please find below one possible solution to your problem using `sf` and `purrr` libraries

**Reprex**

- Code for question 1 only

```r
library(sf)
library(purrr)

parsed<- list( 
  c(-72.6689780388482, -72.6697951984133,-37.8155440677891, -37.8164165487739)
)

parsed %>% 
list(lat = c(pluck(.,1,1), pluck(.,1,2) ), lon = c(pluck(.,1,3), pluck(.,1,4))) %>% 
  .[-1]
```

- Output for question 1 only

```r
#> $lat
#> [1] -72.66898 -72.66980
#> 
#> $lon
#> [1] -37.81554 -37.81642
```

---

- Code for questions 1, 2 and 3

```r
library(sf)
library(purrr)

parsed %>% 
  list(lat = c(pluck(.,1,1), pluck(.,1,2) ), lon = c(pluck(.,1,3), pluck(.,1,4))) %>% 
  .[-1] %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% st_as_sf(., coords = c("lon","lat"), crs = 4326) %>% 
  st_bbox() %>% 
  st_as_sfc() %>% 
  st_sf()
```

- Output for questions 1, 2, 3

```r
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -37.81642 ymin: -72.6698 xmax: -37.81554 ymax: -72.66898
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>                         geometry
#> 1 POLYGON ((-37.81642 -72.669...
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>